# Get value of the cookie from Website with java

Tags: java, session-cookies

When I run a command with Curl to retrieve the cookie for the web site I get different value  when trying with java ..

curl or --cookie-jar or curl or --cookie

Can any one help how to get the cookies from Website by java?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
if (cookies != null)
  for (Cookie ck : cookies) {
    if ("prefResultsPerPage".equals(ck.getName())) {
      String prefValue = ck.getValue();
      ...
    }
```

Taken from http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/servlets/cookies_api_reading.shtml